# Effect of binary variables on binary outcomes

Tags: statistical-significance, binary-data

All
I have two sets of data.  One where people bought and another where they did not.  For each sample in the two sets, I have ~3000 binary independent variables.  Each dataset has about 1000 samples.  The range of positives in the independent variables is 5% through 80%.

The question is: how do I figure out which of the 3000 binary variables has a statistically significant effect on the outcome.  I tried using Fisher Exact Test and that does not seem to be giving intuitive answers.

I am using Python and Scipy for the tests.  Any and all help most welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried Barnard's test?

Comment: Have not.  Will try it.  For the Fisher test, I picked each independent variable separately and ran a Fisher test.  Is that the same I'd do with Barnard's?  Based on a quick search online, it seems to be so.